# Can bazel build dll?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, dll, bazel

I've tried to compile a DLL using bazel for days.
I followed the example [bazel build](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/examples/windows/dll/BUILD) hoping to generate a DLL.
The BUILD file I used is as follow:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "expdtctlib",
    srcs = ["expdtctlib.cpp"],

    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
    linkshared = 1,
)

cc_binary(
    name = "expdetect",
    srcs = ["expdetect.cpp"],
    data = [":expdtctlib.dll"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)
```

I ran the command :

```
bazel build :expdetect
```

But an error said the "expdtctlib.dll" was missing.
Don't bazel first generate "expdtctlib.dll" and then compile "expdetect.cpp"?

Besides,I've tried to use a another way to build DLL.The BUILD file is as follow:

```
cc_library(
    name = "ExpDetector",
    srcs = ["ExpDetector.cc"],
    hdrs = ["ExpDetector.h"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "expdetect",
    srcs = ["expdetect.cc"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
        ":ExpDetector",
    ],
)
```

After a long time compiling,though a EXE file was output and ran well,I could only find .lib and .exp file but the .dll file.

Is there anyone successfully build DLL using bazel?I need your help please.

Comment: There is a "hello world" DLL example in Bazel source tree: [`examples/windows/dll`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/examples/windows/dll).

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for your help.Now the fact is that the bazel outputs only  the .lib file and the .exp file but the .dll file which is also important.

Comment: I'm not sure about your case, but I just run a quick test build of the hello world DLL example and it seems to output `.exp` and `.dll` files correctly in `bazel-out`.

Comment: Btw, if I'm understanding correctly from bits and pieces I've read (e.g. [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4135)), it seems that the usual `.lib` files are produced by Bazel with extension `.ifso`, which is supposed to stand for something like "interface shared object" (basically but what `.lib` files are, but as a general concept).

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks again ! I modefied BUILD file and it seemed to work until a new error occured: "cl.exe failed: error executing command".

Comment: That's some compilation error (`cl.exe` is the MSVC compiler). There should be some compiler error messages, if not maybe passing `--verbose_failures` to `bazel build` gives you more information about the source of the error? (I think that shouldn't trigger rebuilding everything, although you never know with Bazel,,,). I generally use that option and `--experimental_ui`, although I'm not sure what exactly does each of them...

Comment: There are some syntax errors that seems to be unreasonable while I am trying to make explicit link to the DLL.I posted those error on [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140727/error-c-visual-studio-c2227-left-of-init-must-point-to-class-struct-union)   Maybe you can have a check.Thanks!

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you so much! I've solved the problems.

Answer (score 1):

I modified two BUILD files as follow and it worked well!

```
filegroup(
    name = "srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//examples:__pkg__"],
)


cc_binary(
    name = "expdtctlib.dll",
    srcs = ["expdtctlib.cc",
            "expdtctlib.h"],

    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
    linkshared = 1,
)

cc_binary(
    name = "expdetect",
    srcs = ["expdetect.cc"],
    data = [":expdtctlib.dll"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)
```

The one below is in "//tensorflow".

```
exports_files(
    [
        "LICENSE",
        "ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS",
    ],
)

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]) + [
        "//tensorflow/tensorflow/detector0405:srcs",
    ],
)
```

I am not familiar with bazel and c++,but these modification work.I'll read [Bazel Document](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-overview.html) to learn more.

Comment: cc_library should be used for the target expdtctlib.dll